# Magento 2 - Customer Attribute not being saved

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, setup-script

Below is code for creating customer attribute.

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {

        $setup->startSetup();
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'attribute_code', [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Status',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => 'Namespace\Modulename\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\AttributeData',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'attribute_code')
        ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->save();

        //Your install script
    }
}
```

Attribute is displayed on customer edit page in admin but when I set value and save customer, data for custom attribute is not being saved.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You want to enable this attribute for admin customer form then you have to add below form area.

`'adminhtml_customer'`

*By changing*

```
 ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]
        ])
```

**tO**

```
->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'customer_account_edit','adminhtml_customer'
            ]
        ])
```